# if - return - endif statement

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to check if have post_excerpt, then return some things. I want to display somethings below post_excerpt always, even no post_excerpt. I use `<?php endif; ?>`, but it is not worked. 
How to end the if statement?

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $post;

if ( ! $post->post_excerpt ) {
    return;
}

?>

    <p>Have post_excerpt</p>

<?php endif; ?>

    <p>Always display even no post_excerpt</p>
```

I tried to use below:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $post;

if ( ! $post->post_excerpt ):
?>

<p>
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ); ?>
</p>

<?php endif; ?>

    <p>Always display even no post_excerpt</p>
```

I can't show the post_excerpt.

Comment: Where exactly is start of if?

Comment: `endif;` closes an `if ():` statement (that doesn't exist in your code). Read more about [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
      <?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $post;

if ( ! $post->post_excerpt ) {?>
        <p>Always display even no post_excerpt</p>

<?php } else{?>
  <p>Have post_excerpt</p>

    <?php }?>
```

Comment: It still wouldn't display.. there's no else there the "have post_excerpt" paragraph will be sitting behind the return and be unreachable.

Comment: Hands off from `global`

Answer (score 2):

If you `return;` you block the PHP execution.

I think you'd rather want something like this:

```
<?php

if ( ! $post->post_excerpt ):

?>

<p>Have post_excerpt</p>

<?php endif; ?>

<p>Always display even no post_excerpt</p>
```

Note that the construct are like this:

```
if (condition) {
   ...
}
else {
   ...
}

OR this way:

if (condition):
  ...
else:
  ...
endif;
```

You cannot mix those.

**UPDATE** I copied your code but I guess it might have some problems, are you sure about this $post global variable? What framework are you using?

You should first check with var_dump($post) what's in there, otherwise you might want to try:

```
if (!empty($_POST['post_excerpt'])):
```

Comment: Still makes little sense. What that block will do is echo that is has post_excerpt, but the check is the exact opposite. Guessing he really want is to remove to not operater in the if and echo if it is set

Comment: i added a note to my answer, hope that helps.